# Java multithreaded server - each connection returns data. Processing on main thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, serversocket

I am writing a client with an integrated server that should wait indefinitely for new connections - and handle each on a Thread.

I want to process the received byte array in a system wide available message handler **on the main thread**. However, currently the processing is obviously done on the client thread.

I've looked at Futures, submit() of ExecutorService, but as I create my Client-Connections within the Server, the data would be returned to the Server thread. How can I return it from there onto the main thread (in a synchronized packet store maybe?) to process it without blocking the server?

My current implementation looks like this:

```
    public class Server extends Thread {
    private int port;
    private ExecutorService threadPool;

    public Server(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        // 50 simultaneous connections
        threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
    }

    public void run() {
        try{
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(this.port);
            System.out.println("Listening on Port " + this.port);
            Socket connection;

            while(true){
                try {
                    connection = listener.accept();
                    System.out.println("Accepted client " + connection.getInetAddress());
                    connection.setSoTimeout(4000);

                    ClientHandler conn_c= new ClientHandler(connection);
                    threadPool.execute(conn_c);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("IOException on connection: " + e);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            threadPool.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
    private Socket connection;

    ClientHandler(Socket connection) {
        this.connection=connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Read data from the InputStream, buffered
            int count;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            // While there is data in the stream, read it
            while ((count = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            is.close();
            out.close();

            System.out.println("Disconnect client " + connection.getInetAddress());
            connection.close();
            // handle the received data
            MessageHandler.handle(out.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException on socket read: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;

    }
}
```

**Update:** The robust way seems to be what TomTom suggested - using the newer java.nio instead. As this project is of limited use and more of an experiment, I'd like to know the best way using it with java.io/java.net :)

Comment: So why exactly would you want to process these on main thread? NIO does allow you to do non-blocking processing (and libraries like Netty make it easier to use), but is there specific reason to avoid multi-threaded approach?

Comment: Each of these incoming messages might produce new outgoing connections and thus, new incoming connections on this server and I would like to avoid running everything after message capture in new threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my option, you can use a sync object to chat with the main thread, after your add client connections to the pool, the main thread can block at the accept and the sync object, after you client handle it, put the processed connection socket and response to a queue, and then wakeup the sync object, so the main thread can then get something from the queue and process it, after main thread handle it, block at accept and wait at the sync object.

Basically, your architecture is a simple/direct way, the newly way is use the java nio, to get the more concurrency server and get better performance, also the nio is not the best way...

Comment: Using a synchronized queue for incoming packets in the main thread was one idea that came to my mind as well, but I was unsure of the best way to return the data received in the Client Thread back to the main thread. I'll have a closer look into that, thanks! :) (And, for the time being, as this is a very limited project of use, i'd like to stick with java.io, because I had not used nio so far.

Answer (score 0):

That iwll not scale. Any reason you do that? Plus you waste tons of memory - you dont need a thread PER SOCKET. Use a better Java IO library. Like the one available as part of Java for like 10 years or so (NGIO?). It handles x threads with one socket, just returning data.

Comment: Don't you mean one thread with X sockets?. One thread per socket won't scale above 10,000 connections but this is usually enough. I would be more concerned about the fixed size thread pool of size 50! A cached thread pool might be more approriate. ;)

Comment: One thread per socket was what was recommended in several MultiThreaded Server examples. I'll try it without threads, but that keeps my question open as to how to return the data continously without blocking the server thread. (The fixed size thread pool was my silly attempt to address that. I will switch to a cached thread pool)

Comment: Well, you will find a LOT of outdated examples. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O - the section on selectors. Bascially you havea list of Sockets, then select those with waiting data, then go on processing those. No need to have one thread waiting for data per socket. One thread can handle 1000 or 2000 sockets, selecting the ones with data in a loop. This was added in jdk 5 timeframe, it seems. YOur sample code probably is ANCIENT.

Comment: old styles tend to come into fashion again. ;) NIO non-blocking sockets was the best around when it was released in Java 1.4.  I am not alone in finding that using NIO with a blocking threads can be the fastest, most efficient way to manage connections in Java 6. IMHO, Using the dispatcher model adds alot of complexity for little value in modern systems.

Comment: Well, you will also find that a alot of stuff coming "into fashion" comes into fashion from people who dont really know waht they say. Example is the nice rush of "I dont use a database, I go nosql" from people which mostly dont even know WHY a relational database works as it works (relational theory). NIO + one blocking thread per X sockets (1000, 2000 etc.) is good. This is not "one thread per socket", though, and the question is also whether the gains have a real benefit. They do not for me - and I have an app distributing financial data to processing services in real time.